# make switch button show another form

Tags: jquery, html, material-design, bootstrap-4

I have this switch on/off button, I want to make it shows another form when clicking on and when you click off I want to get back the 1st form

here's my code :

```
<h3>transfer</h3>
<input type="checkbox" id="id-name--1" name="set-name" class="switch-input">
  <label for="id-name--1" class="switch-label"> <span id ="on"class="toggle--on">market</span><span class="toggle--off"> bank</span></label>
  </div>
```

I have tried using jquery toggle() but it's only showing the 2nd form without making the 1st form disappeared

```
$('#buttonLogin').on('click', function(e){
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('class1')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're just toggling one form without doing anything to the other one.

```
$('#buttonLogin').on('click', function(e){
    $("#another_Box_Div").toggle();
    $("#login_Box_Div").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('class1')
});
```

Comment: Did you assign an ID to the container of first form?

Comment: My pleasure to help.